# Is it wiser to store exploded or imploded data (in a database)?

Tags: size

I will be retrieving data which are provided as json encoded strings, but the strings can be very long, such as up to 200 000 characters.

Speaking of storage size, should I store the json as one big string (and decode it whenever i need it), or already split it into maybe a hundred columns ? (various types of data, tiny ints, etc).

Processing data isn't a problem, i care more about the storage capacity.

Thanks

Comment: If you don't care about the processing, why use a database? Flat files don't take as much space.

Comment: I mean, processing the json decoding is not a big deal, but i will need to store the data on the long term.